# How to edit floating view added to scene dock in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a view controller on my storyboard set up with a tableview.   I want to have another view as a floating view on top of the table view. So, I drag a view (actually a toolbar object) and drop it into the scene dock so that in code I can add it to the subviews and position it so that it floats.  I have no questions about the coding; just laying out the view in storyboard.

How do I open the view object that I added to the scene dock so that I can add buttons to it, etc., and design it visually?

I know it's possible since I did it accidentally in another project.  The toolbar was in the view controller's scene dock *and* displayed separately with it's own scene dock. It's very frustrating knowing it can be done, but not knowing how to do it!

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [bikibird.com](http://bikibird.com/toolbar.png))</sub>
!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is how I did it (also by accident).

I had created an (IBAction) and was trying to connect to a button. So I drug a line from my code to the button (in the list of items). For some reason it wouldn't connect so it seemed to hover over it for a few seconds.

All of a sudden the view (with the button) popped out and displayed next to my uiviewcontroller just like you described. I had done this also by accident, but this is the first time I managed to get it to work for me.

Let me know if this works for you as well!!!

Comment: I just tried this again on another project and sure enough, it worked again. They key is to not let go - just drag and hold over the object in the list to the left.

Comment: This works reliably. I wish they would make this an easier - so far the only way I can get them to "pop out" is by dragging an IBAction onto the toolbar. But it does work reliably.

Comment: it does not appear to work with just IBOutlets, has to be an IBAction what a nice "feature."

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to show a view like in your picture, but to design a view visually i put it, for example, as head view on my `TableView`, design it and put it back to the dock.
It's only a workaround, but that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was drag a UI object (in my case it was a UISlider) from the object explorer on the right into the view I wanted to pop out in the scene explorer on the left